# Problems with Session for Sorting my GridView

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

I have problems with the `Session["TaskTable"]` as Datasource for my GridView.
When I open the .aspx site the first time the `Session["TaskTable"]` is null, if I reload the page (F5) the `Session["TaskTable"]` is my Datatable `taskTable`. How could that be? I'm only able to sort if I first reload my page. Any ideas? Thanks

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            DataTable taskTable = new DataTable("TaskList");
            taskTable = dtCloned;                
            Session["TaskTable"] = taskTable;
            GV_Projekte.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            GV_Projekte.DataBind();

         }
     }
```

And for the sorting of my GridView

```
protected void gv_Sorting(object sender, GridViewSortEventArgs e)
    {
        DataTable dt = Session["TaskTable"] as DataTable;

        if (dt != null)
        {
            //Sort the data.
            dt.DefaultView.Sort = e.SortExpression + " " + GetSortDirection(e.SortExpression);
            GV_Projekte.DataSource = Session["TaskTable"];
            GV_Projekte.DataBind();
        }
    }

    private string GetSortDirection(string column)
    {
        // By default, set the sort direction to ascending.
        string sortDirection = "ASC";

        // Retrieve the last column that was sorted.
        string sortExpression = ViewState["SortExpression"] as string;

        if (sortExpression != null)
        {
            // Check if the same column is being sorted.
            // Otherwise, the default value can be returned.
            if (sortExpression == column)
            {
                string lastDirection = ViewState["SortDirection"] as string;
                if ((lastDirection != null) && (lastDirection == "ASC"))
                {
                    sortDirection = "DESC";
                }
            }
        }

        // Save new values in ViewState.
        ViewState["SortDirection"] = sortDirection;
        ViewState["SortExpression"] = column;

        return sortDirection;
    }
```

Comment: dtCloned comes from where? Trace the code at Line: taskTable = dtCloned;  and see if dtCloned is not null

Comment: dtCloned is filled, thanks but the next post gave me the answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because of Page.IsPostback condition When page is not postback it assigned session to a variable now this value will be there untill session will expire whatever session time out is there.

Take following exercise.

```
 protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (Session["a"]==null)
        {
            Response.Write("Session is empty");
        }
        else
        {
            Response.Write("Session is not empty");
            Response.Write(Session["a"].ToString());
        }
        if (!Page.IsPostBack)
        {
            Session["a"] = "Jalpesh";
        }
    }
```

Here in blank page I'm doing same thing you are doing but first time page will load at that time it will print 'session is empty' but after that session will not be empty till session expires so it will print 'session is not empty'.

So if you need session value null you have to assign session to null somewhere.

Comment: Thanks for the information, now I can look how I can change the use of the session

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution, the function `gv_Sorting` has to stand BEFORE the `page_load` so that it is filled correctly the first time. See also the example where I've got the code from:
[http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.sorting%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)